# Encrypted disk image with a (n accepted) password, now disk utility refuses to decrypt said image with error "Passphrase too long", how to resolve?

Tags: disk-utility

On MacOS, using its disk utility, I created an **encrypted** volume from a folder using the following option listed under File -> New Image -> Image from Folder...:

[image: Image from Folder... menu item]

Since I always use `pass` as my password manager, I always opt for the maximum length password. This I did in my case here too, but I was surprised when I generated a password of length 500, and disk utility accepted it without an issue. It then created my image, encrypted it and now I'm greeted with the error "Passphrase too long" when trying to decrypt the image using the very same ***accepted*** password as can be seen here:

[image: "Passphrase is too long" error message]

I tried the only thing I could think of, and that is to check the max length (it's 256 characters), and try to cut down the length 500 password to said max length, but my password is again, rejected. This time without the `Passphrase too long` error, but with simply the `incorrect passphrase` error.

Does anybody know by any chance if the passphrase is set to some default value in this case?

Comment: Seems like a design error which should be reported to Apple. At the very least, Disk Utility should warn you that the password is too long. Can you mount it with a `diskutil` command?